# Two numbers multiplied randomly

Tags: probability, number-theory

Assume that two numbers choosen randomly from all m digits and n digits are multiplied then what can we say about probability of that number of being $(m+n)$ digits ?

My attempt :

I started with very basic case let $m = n = 1 $ . Then chances of getting two digit number will be
$$=\frac{81-23}{81}=71.60 %$$

Now let
$m=1$ and $n=2$ . Then there are 9 one digit and 90 two digit numbers , total 810 results . Now if multiply 1 to 9 one by one by $[10,99]$ then number of $m+n = 3$ digit numbers , =
$$\small0+50+66+75+80+83+85+87+88=614$$
So there are 75.80 % chances .

My Questions ::

1.when we increased m or n chances of getting m+n digit number increased . is this true ?

2. If we think this problem like there are two sets we multiplying set M of $9.10^{m-1}$ elements and set N of $9.10^{n-1}$ elements . If we multiply all elements of set M one by one ( ascending order ) by set N and count number of m + n digits and draw graph then number gradually increases and becomes  constant and graph of m+n-1 sharply falls to low value . So is this enough to show that the probability of getting m+ n digits will approach 1 as numbers get large ?
3. Can we derive any formula or approximation here ?

Answer (score 1):

For $m$ and $n$ large, call your $m$- and $n$-digit numbers $x 10^m$ and $y 10^n$, where $x, y \in [0.1, 1)$. We want to know the probability that $xy \in [0.1, 1)$. For large $m$ and $n$ this tends to the area of the region $\{(x, y) \in [0.1,1]^2 : xy \geq 0.1\}$ divided by $0.9^2$. This is an integral which I will leave to you.